# How to merge two JSON file with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to do a python script that merge 2 json files for example:

First file: students.json

```
{"John Smith":{"age":16, "id": 1}, ...., "Paul abercom":{"age":18, "id": 764}}
```

Second file: teacher.json

```
{"Agathe Magesti":{"age":36, "id": 765}, ...., "Tom Ranliver":{"age":54, "id": 801}}
```

So in a first time, to not lose any informations I modify the files to add the status of each person like that:

```
{"John Smith":{"age":16, "id": 1, "status":"student"}, ...., "Paul abercom":{"age":18, "id": 764, "status":"student"}}

{"Agathe Magesti":{"age":36, "id": 765, "status":"teacher"}, ...., "Tom Ranliver":{"age":54, "id": 801, "status":"teacher"}}
```

To do that I did the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
type_student = pd.read_json('student.json')
type_student.loc["status"] = "student"
type_student.to_json("testStudent.json")
type_teacher = pd.read_json('teacher.json')
type_teacher.loc["status"] = "teacher"
type_teacher.to_json("testTeacher.json")
with open("testStudent.json") as data_file:
   data_student = json.load(data_file)
with open("testTeacher.json") as data_file:
   data_teacher = json.load(data_file)
```

What I want to do is to merge data_student and data_teacher and print the resulting JSON in a json file, but I can only use the standard library, pandas, numpy and scipy.

After some tests I realize that some teacher are also students which can be a problem for the merge.

Comment: You don't need pandas to mess with JSON data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your JSON files contain "objects" as top-level structures. These map to Python dictionaries. So this should be easy using just Python. Just update the first dictionary with the second.

```
import json

with open("mel1.json") as fo:
    data1 = json.load(fo)

with open("mel2.json") as fo:
    data2 = json.load(fo)

data1.update(data2)

with open("melout.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(data1, fo)
```

Comment: What will become the duplicate data? Will their status become something like "status": ["teacher","student"]

Comment: @mel it will be replaced. I presume you already took care of the duplicates when you edited it. If not, just a little more code is needed to loop over one and update the value on a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) the two data frames before converting to JSON:

```
pd.concat([data_teacher, data_student], axis=1).to_json()
```

Comment: I can't edit your post because it's inferior to 6 caracters, but can you rectify: type_pd.concat by pd.concat
I get the following error: ValueError: DataFrame columns must be unique for orient='columns'.
I thinks it come from that some teacher are also students and when I load my json into the dataframe, pandas is inversing the index and column, i guess because it's a nested JSON.

Comment: It's difficult to know what is causing the problem without seeing the actual data. The proposed solution works with `type_student` and `type_teacher` instead of `data_student` and `data_teacher`. I suggest you take a look at the documentation for `concat`.